# Angular template driven form on submit validation

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

In angular js, we have $submitted to populate error messages on submit click.

How can we display all validation errors on submit click in Angular

HTML:

```
<form #nameForm="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="saveNameForm(formModel)">
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="inputName" class="form-control-label"> Name</label>
   <input type="text" id="inputName" name="lotCode [(ngModel)]="formModel.name" #lotCode="ngModel" aria-describedby="nameHelp"
     autocomplete="new-password" required>
   <small id="nameHelp" class="text-danger" *ngIf="lotCode.invalid && lotCode.touched">Required</small>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputDescription" class="form-control-label"> Description</label>
    <input type="text" id="inputDescription" name="desCode" [(ngModel)]="formModel.description" #desCode="ngModel" aria-describedby="descriptionHelp"
     autocomplete="new-password" required>
    <small id="descriptionHelp" class="text-danger" *ngIf="desCode.invalid && desCode.touched">Required</small>
</div>

<button type="submit">Submit </button>
</form>
```

Component:

```
 export class AppComponent  {
 formModel: FormModel= new FormModel();
 saveNameForm(formModel){
 console.log(formModel)
 }
 }
 export class FormModel {
 name: string;
 description:string;
 }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rizsuy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8jaaqz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

You should use a variable to set submitted
if submitted then will display error

Comment: Please use hyperlinks only to support your answer, not as the core of your answer. If the link dies at some point in the future, your answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses the same [form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) that native HTML5 does. Just do this in an Angular context. In the following example, we can use `*ngIf` to control the display of the messages, and `.dirty` and `.touched` to determine if the user interacted with the input.

Example from [docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation):

```
<input id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
  required minlength="4" appForbiddenName="bob"
  [(ngModel)]="hero.name" #name="ngModel" >

  <div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)"
  class="alert alert-danger">

  <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
    Name is required.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">
    Name must be at least 4 characters long.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.forbiddenName">
    Name cannot be Bob.
  </div>
</div>
```